# Why non-linear fiber capacity limit decrease for higher signal-noise ratios?

Tags: optics, quantum-optics, signal-processing, fiber-optics, non-linear-optics

[image: decreases of spectral efficiency after certain SNR shown here]In fiber optics communication, there is the concept of *nonlinear Shannon limit* (see e.g. [this article](https://research.aston.ac.uk/portal/files/14259032/Nonlinear_Shannon_limit_and_the_need_for_new_fibres.pdf)), implying that the communication capacity of an optical fiber decreases for high SNR. I don’t understand this concept, and specially the origin of the decrease of the spectral efficiency decrease after certain increase of SNR.
I have read the post ([Negative SNR and Shannon–Hartley theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/297652/)) on Shannon capacity theorem but it didn't clear up my concept.

I need these answer to explain the 1Tbps capacity limit of single mode fiber. So it will be helpful for me if anyone answer me the second part(cause of limit of single mode transmission) also

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. The shannon limit ($\rm B = C \log_2(1+SNR)$) is a monotonically increasing function of SNR. It doesn't fall after a *certain* SNR. It falls whenever you decrease the SNR.

Comment: Also, the Shannon limit takes the channel bit rate (C) as a given, so it's not a great place to start when estimating the bandwidth of a physical channel.

Comment: @ThePhoton No, the non-linearity is the deviation from that equation; it's observed when you transfer over long distances with high signal power. The stronger electric field causes a change in the refractive indiex of the silica in the wires. Can't find a reference, but I'm quite sure I've read that somewhere.

Comment: @Chair that is a real limit on fiber capacity, but it's not called the "nonlinear Shannon limit".

Comment: @ThePhoton : Apparently, it is called so: see e.g. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7537418/ : *“many works suggest the existence of an upper limit—usually but improperly referred to as the nonlinear Shannon limit—to the rate at which information can be reliably transmitted through the optical fiber channel, regardless of the available optical power”*

Comment: Why is this question on hold. If the question seems unclear, it‘s actually because the OP does not know its answer (hence the question !). The concept of nonlinear Shanon limit is a widely studied physical limit of optical fibres, and seems on topic. (If the question is reopened, I promise an answer)

Comment: Sorry for some incomplete info. I have seen that if SNR increases spectral efficiency increases upto a certain limit & then start to decrease though SNR increasing which i meant in question that why that decreases

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question. @HasanShuvo please add a few details to the question, like perhaps some articles which indicate that the nonlinear Shannon limit is a formally observed concept. I'm quite sure that the lack of information in the question made it appear random. I don't really see the point of linking the Physics SE article about negative SNR... perhaps some excerpts from that would help make the question clearer..

Comment: actually if i could attach the graph of that what i am saying it would be cleared to all but i have seen no option here to attach photo.

Comment: I have added details of my question by editing. still if something unclear tell me.And I am new here so there's some mistake may done by me following the rules of this site. but please i need the answer of the question for my research.Help me @Frédéric Grosshans

Comment: @HasanShuvo Images would be useful. There should be an option to attach a picture next to the options for bold and italics text (depends on the device though). Otherwise, you can put a link to an image in the comments and somebody who's familiar with the system will be able to edit it in and show you how the markdown for that looks.

Comment: @Chair : I have reworded the OP’s question a bit (But I can’t answer it because it’s on hold). And included a link to a paper which includes graphs of such decrease.

Comment: @Frédéric Grosshans thank u for editing. I wrote that paper that you have linked and i exactly asked about those graph.I Now also added such a graph in my question. But how it can be reopened?

Comment: @HasanShuvo: The figure its nice, but its source should be explicit too.

Comment: @Frédéric Grosshans I took that from a slide whose link is not available to me now. Btw, as my question is on hold & you want to answer it. Is there any way(any social media or email) by which you could answer it. I don't know more about rules here so asked that as i need my answer badly

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans, thanks, that is a new term for me. But what's really going on isn't that the Shannon limit is being modified --- rather in the presence of nonlinear behavior, the SNR doesn't depend linearly on signal power.

Comment: A short answer before your question gathers enough reopen votes: The key point, as shown by the graph ith non-linear signal-signal interactions. It means that, when you have high power into the fiber, non-linear interaction induces crosstalk between channels. Which means that the signal in one channel induce more noise in other channel, so, past some threshold, boosting the signal power increases the effective noise, and actually decrease the effective SNR and the capacity.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Indeed, but to know this, one needs to effectively know the answer of the question...

Comment: @ Frédéric Grosshans Thank you so much. I have searched & read so many files.At last got some point. I will be grateful if you tell me how multimode fiber cross that shannon limit? just as they have likewise more single modes avilable in one core,for that reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capacity of a channel of bandwidth $W$ is known since the 1940‘s to be given by the [Shannon limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem):
$$C=W \log (1+\mathit{SNR}), $$
where $\mathit{SNR}$ is the signal to noise ratio. In an optical fibre in the linear regime, the noise is essentially independent of the signal, and that means one just has to increase the signal power to increase the rate. Mathematically, an infinite rate seems possible, but the logarithmic dependence makes the increase really expensive. That is the reason why, historically, the capacity increase of fibers has been more focused on increasing the bandwidth $W$,through WDM. However this $W$ increase has some limits, and people also work at increasing the power.

The Shannon formula ensures that, to have a linear increase in capacity, one needs an exponential increase in $\mathit{SNR}$, and therefore, an exponential increas of optical of power. Which  means that, at some point, nonlinear effects are noticable, and create what is sometimes named “*the nonlinear Shannon limit*”. The main effect is that the channel is non longer an additive channel: the signal as the output of the channel cannot be analyzed as the addition of the input signal and an independent noise, and the above formula is no longer valid. Effectively, some part of the signal acts as noise to other parts of the signal, creating an effective $SNR$ which decreases with increasing signal power past a power threshold, and therefore a decreasing capacity above a given optimal input power (at -$5\text{ dBM}\simeq300\text{ µW}$ on your graph.

As far as I understood (this is not my research topic), the concept of *nonlinear Shannon limit* is an active research topic: it has no clean formulation, and some researcher claim that, contrasting to the Shannon limit,  this is not a universal limit but an artifact of current encoding techniques.

Comment: ''some part of the signal acts as noise to other parts of the signal''--why? Is that because the signal in one channel induce more noise in other channel

Comment: Basically,*linear* means that you can look at the signal as the sum of his parts, and that they do not interact with the others. *Nonlinear* means that this assumption is not true anymore. On your graph, the difference between the green curve (1 channel) and the red curve (WDM, that is multiple channels) shows that the dominant effect is indeed inter-channel interactions